# React Native - The Color of TouchableOpacity Button Should Change Without Map

Tags: react-native, button, touchableopacity

I have only two buttons, and I want their backgroundColor to be changed when pressing. I don't want to use `map` as there are only two buttons. I have tried some ways to approach what I expect, but I am at a loss what to do.

RoundedButtonSet :

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

const RoundedButtonSet = ({ firstBtn, secondBtn, contentStyle }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, contentStyle]}>
      <RoundedButtons firstBtn={firstBtn} secondBtn={secondBtn} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

RoundedButtons :

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btn: {
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.very_light_pink,
    borderRadius: 6,
    paddingVertical: 13,
    height: 40,
  },
  btnTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    color: colors.very_light_pink_five,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  left: {
    borderTopRightRadius: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    borderColor: colors.very_light_pink,
  },
  right: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
  },
  backgroundColor: {
    backgroundColor: colors.iris,
  },
  textColor: {
    color: colors.white_two,
  },
});

const RoundedButtons = ({ firstBtn, secondBtn, contentStyle, onPress }) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, contentStyle]}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.btn, styles.left, isClicked && styles.backgroundColor]}
        onPress={() => setIsClicked(!isClicked)}
      >
        <Text style={[styles.btnTextStyle, isClicked && styles.textColor]}>
          {firstBtn}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.btn, styles.right]}
        onPress={() => setIsClicked()}
      >
        <Text style={[styles.btnTextStyle]}>{secondBtn}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

RoundedButtons.propTypes = {
  firstBtn: Text.propTypes,
  secondBtn: Text.propTypes,
};

export default RoundedButtons;
```

Should I give `index` directly to each button? I have got this idea, but the problem is I have no idea how to access..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a simple state to keep track of which button is pressed and use that to apply styles conditionally.

**Here is the working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/vigorous-stroopwafels)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btn: {
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'pink',
    borderRadius: 6,
    paddingVertical: 13,
    height: 40,
  },
  btnTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    color: 'pink',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  left: {
    borderTopRightRadius: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    borderColor: 'pink',
  },
  right: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
  },
  backgroundColor: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  textColor: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

const RoundedButtons = ({ firstBtn, secondBtn, contentStyle, onPress }) => {
  const [clickedBtn, setIsClicked] = useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(clickedBtn);
  }, [clickedBtn]);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, contentStyle]}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.btn,
          styles.left,
          clickedBtn == 1 && styles.backgroundColor,
        ]}
        onPress={() => setIsClicked(1)}>
        <Text
          style={[styles.btnTextStyle, clickedBtn == 1 && styles.textColor]}>
          firstBtn
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.btn,
          styles.right,
          clickedBtn == 2 && styles.backgroundColor,
        ]}
        onPress={() => setIsClicked(2)}>
        <Text
          style={[styles.btnTextStyle, clickedBtn == 2 && styles.textColor]}>
          secondBtn
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

RoundedButtons.propTypes = {
  firstBtn: Text.propTypes,
  secondBtn: Text.propTypes,
};

export default RoundedButtons;
```

Comment: Right.. this is what I have heard to solve, but couldn't figure it out how to make it. I guess I still have to dig into this more! Thank you!!